# What does "Object 'Workbook Failed'" in the context of a SaveAs operation?

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot get this SavePath to work correctly. The SavePath has been defined and when I scroll over SavePath it is showing the correct path. I continue to receive a SaveAs of:

> Object 'Workbook Failed'

The issue is the last line. What can I try next?

```
Sub UpdateData()
'This macro will activate on click of update button and will take the information from the Plaq. Spot Master turnover log and insert it into the rail turnover database'


Dim wb1 As Workbook

Dim SpotLog1 As Worksheet

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim Dates As Date

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SPOT LOG").Range("A4") = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Date in Cell A4", vbCritical, "No Date Entered"
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

Set SpotLog1 = wb1.Sheets("Spot Log")

Dates = SpotLog1.Range("A4")

Dim Month As String
Dim Year As String

Month = Format(Dates, "mmmm")
Year = Format(Dates, "yyyy")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim SavePath
Dim Temp
Temp = "A:\Turnover Logs\Temp"
SavePath = "A:\Turnover Logs\ " & Year & "\" & Month & "\ Turnover " & Format(Dates, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsm"

On Error Resume Next
wb1.SaveAs Filename:=Temp
On Error GoTo 0
wb1.SaveAs Filename:=SavePath
```

I have tried to rewrite the path but it won't correct the path.

Comment: If you are saving it as a XLSM then you need to secify the type too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat

Comment: Try without the space in `"A:\Turnover Logs\ "`

Answer (score 0):

### Creating File Backups

```vb
Sub UpdateData()
' This macro will activate on click of the update button
' and will take the information from the Plaq.
' Spot Master turnover log and insert it into the rail turnover database.'
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "A:\Turnover Logs\"

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("SPOT LOG")
    Dim dateCell As Range: Set dateCell = ws.Range("A4")
    
    If Not IsDate(dateCell.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter the Date in Cell A4", vbCritical, "No Date Entered"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim fDate As Date: fDate = dateCell.Value
    
    Dim DateString As String: DateString = Format(fDate, "mm-dd-yyyy")
    Dim YearString As String: YearString = Format(fDate, "yyyy")
    Dim MonthString As String: MonthString = Format(fDate, "mmmm")
    
    Dim TempFilePath As String: TempFilePath = FolderPath & "Temp" & ".xlsm"
    Debug.Print TempFilePath 
    Dim SaveFilePath As String: SaveFilePath = FolderPath & YearString & "\" _
        & MonthString & "\Turnover " & DateString & ".xlsm"
    Debug.Print SaveFilePath 
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
    
    wb.SaveAs TempFilePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    wb.SaveAs SaveFilePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    'wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```